# Как спарсить текст после второго слеша?

Tags: delphi

Как спарсить текст после второго слеша, то есть **текст3**

Маска текста такая:

`текст1/текст2/текст3
текст1/текст2/текст3`

текст1, текст2, текст3 всегда разные, поэтому регулярки тут не подойдут.

Comment: Если мы знаем что формат строки именно такой (и его не стоит проверять и т.д.) то можно и регулярным выражением, код на JS, дельфей на знаю, но переписать не составит труда

    function getLastSlashSeparatedValue( string ) {
      var re = /\/([\S]+)$/;
      var res = string.match( re );
      return string.match ? res[1] : null;
    }
    var res = getLastSlashSeparatedValue("test1/test2/test3");
    // -> res === "test3"

Comment: Или вам нужна функция которая принимает строку и позицию и возвращает значение (если оно есть)?

Comment: ЛОЛ, сегодня что, день такой? Это же идиотизм, пихать регулярки куда не надо!

Comment: @karmadro4 - будьте так добры опишите то как вы видите решение этой задачи? Мне непонятно ваше недоумение

Раз Вы, так-же, минусуете вариант с разбиенем строки и считаете что, регулярка здесь не к месту, мне очень интересно как бы Вы решили-бы подобную задачу.

Посимвольно в цикле? Если да - чем это значительно лучше регулярки?

В общем - жду мастер класса :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, тот вариант - нечитаемые макароны из индийского ресторанчика. См. [сюда](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.LastDelimiter), например. Даже на JavaScript решается в аналогичные три строки.

> чем это значительно лучше регулярки?

А сами-то как думаете?

Answer (score 2):

Если именно в delphi, а не на чистом pascal, то можно использовать [`SplitString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString) из `System.StrUtils`.

```
uses StrUtils
...
text3 := SplitString("текст1/текст2/текст3", "/");
```

Comment: А переменная `text3` у вас что такое?

Comment: @KromStern просто заранее объявленная переменная. дельфи нет, снизу есть заминусованный удаленный ответ про SplitString. так что код я наугад писал